# Threads execute the command but stop my program

Tags: c, pthreads

First, I'm not familiar with threading, I wanted to a task without waiting for another to end and I've been told it was the best solution.

So I wrote this code which is supposed to play a sound whenever I pass a value in `tab[]` to `true` (I removed parts of the code that work properly but don't refer to threads):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define DRUM0 25
#define DRUM1 24
#define DRUM2 23


void *kick(void *arg)
{
        printf("Kick");
        execlp("/usr/bin/omxplayer", " ", "/home/pi/sounds/kick.wav", NULL);
        (void) arg;
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *boom(void *arg)
{
        printf("Boom");
        execlp("/usr/bin/omxplayer", " ", "/home/pi/sounds/boom.wav", NULL);
        (void) arg;
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *tom(void *arg)
{
        printf("tom");
        execlp("/usr/bin/omxplayer", " ", "/home/pi/sounds/tom.wav", NULL);
        (void) arg;
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main()
{
        pthread_t kicking, booming, toming;
        while(1){
                if(tab[0] == 1)
                {
                        if(pthread_create(&kicking, NULL, kick, NULL) == -1) {
                                perror("pthread_create");
                                return EXIT_FAILURE;
                        }
                }

                if(tab[1] == 1)
                {
                        if(pthread_create(&booming, NULL, boom, NULL) == -1) {
                                perror("pthread_create");
                                return EXIT_FAILURE;
                        }
                }
                if(tab[2] == 1)
                {
                        if(pthread_create(&toming, NULL, tom, NULL) == -1) {
                                perror("pthread_create");
                                return EXIT_FAILURE;
                        }
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

So when I pass a value of tab to 1 it activates the corresponding thread but then it gets stuck and doesn't do anything.
In this case it plays the sound I want and then gets stuck at these lines (my program is still running but nothing happens when I pass another value to 1 or 0) :

```
Audio codec pcm_s24le channels 1 samplerate 44100 bitspersample 24
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
```

I don't know where it comes from and didn't find issue like this anywhere. I expect the problem to come from omxplayer or my use of execlp but I still don't know how to solve my problem so if you can help thank you in advance !

---

[EDIT] Ok so I've also tried to use `fork()` :

```
void *kick(void *arg)
{
        int pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0)
        {
                printf("Kick");
                execlp("/usr/bin/omxplayer", " ", "/home/pi/sounds/kick.wav", NULL);
                (void) arg;
        }
        else
                wait();

        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

But it gives me a pretty weird log of omxplayer :

```
Raspberry Pi Drums
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.have a nice day ;)
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.have a nice day ;)
```

And this repeats like 10 or more times even with a `ctrl+c`

Comment: `exec`*`()` replaces the program in current process. (Therefore, it's often combined with `fork()`.)

Comment: Calling `execlp()` in the threads is not ok, take a look here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588387/what-happens-to-threads-when-exec-is-called]

Comment: `fork()` before you `exec*()` ... `exec*()` replaces the *process*. Alternatively, use `posix_spawn()`. You can then `waitpid()` in your thread.

Comment: @Scheff Thank you I've tried `fork()` by putting `int pid;    pid=fork();` at the beginning of the threads (so before `execlp()`) but same here I'm not familiar with it so I may not be using it the right way

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt So what should I do ?

Comment: Like others have said. call `fork()` + `execlp()` or just `system()`

Comment: with `fork()` keep in mind it returns *twice* once in the parent process (returning the child pid) and once in the cheild (returning 0). So it must always be combined with an if/else or better with switch/case (three cases because auf possible errors)

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Thank you, but i don't really understand what I should put in the child and the parent with `fork()`... I've put the `execlp  ()` in the the child and `wait()` in the father but it actually messes up `omxplayer`

Comment: exec() in child and wait() in parent is ok. Maybe you can update the question and post the code containing fork() as 'what IVe also tried is ...'

Comment: In this context, you could use `system()` instead of having to work with `fork()` and `exec*()`.  Your code, though, is unthrottled; you will have a ridiculous number of threads running in almost no time at all as shown.  Further, you never join the threads but you don't make them, detached either; you'll run out of resources rather quickly.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I've put the edit

Comment: @JonathanLeffler since I was using an infinite loop I didn't think joining the threads would be necessary, and the sound I play don't exceed 1 sec so I was counting on that to stop the process. But I was thinking of cleaning that, by closing everything after I could make all this work properly

Comment: hmm I would use `waitpid( pid, &status, 0 )` insthead. `wait()` returns if any child process returns but you want to wait for a dedicated one. Btw. `wait() also requires an argument. Didn't the compiler warn you?

Comment: Another thing is that you pass " " as argv[0] to omxplayer. Very unusual and could be the reason it 'gets messed up'. Pass the program name (with or without path) instead

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Ok I've made the change (no it didn't warn me..) However i now get `tvservice-client: Failed to connect to TV service: -1` non stop. I will try with another function to execute omxplayer

Comment: Then look for better compiler switches ;-) Calling a function with either not having a prototype or using the wrong signature should both at least throw a warning